# How can a fund have negative "Net Other Assets"?

Tags: mutual-funds, money-market

This is the composition of the Fidelity Government Money Market Fund ([SPAXX](https://fundresearch.fidelity.com/mutual-funds/composition/31617H102)):

[image: Screenshot]

How is it possible that the "Net Other Assets" is negative?

Answer (score 4):

> Net Other Assets include cash and receivables ***and payables*** related to open security or capital stock trades.

Presumably they have higher payables (a short-term liability) than receivables and cash, resulting in a net negative "asset" category.

Comment: How could a money market mutual fund have more payables than receivables and cash?

Comment: It depends on netting agreements and credit terms (how long they have to settle) they have with counterparties, They may explain it in the annual reports and/or financial statements.